# Qt oscilloscope example

Tags: qt, qwt

I was told there is a qt oscilloscope example available online, not sure if it's by Qt QDevelop or someone else. Can someone give me a link to this project? I need this to test something I am working on in Qt. I need to generate some data, specifically a sine wave to do some testing with an application I am developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.oscilloscope-lib.com/oscilloscope_DLL.zip but it's not based on Qt, though.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a [Qwt - Qt Widgets for Technical Applications](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/index.html)